# cbind 2 dataframes with different number of rows

Tags: r, cbind

I have two lists named `h` and `g`.
They each contain 244 dataframes and they look like the following:

```
h[[1]]
   year  avg    hr   sal
1  2010  0.300  31   2000
2  2011  0.290  30   4000
3  2012  0.275  14    600
4  2013  0.280  24    800 
5  2014  0.295  18   1000
6  2015  0.330  26   7000
7  2016  0.315  40   9000

g[[1]]
   year  pos  fld     
1  2010  A   0.990
2  2011  B   0.995
3  2013  C   0.970
4  2014  B   0.980
5  2015  D   0.990
```

I want to `cbind` these two dataframes.
But as you see, they have different number of rows.
I want to combine these dataframes so that the rows with the same year will be combined in one row. And I want the empty spaces to be filled with `NA`.
The result I expect looks like this:

```
   year  avg    hr   sal   pos   fld
1  2010  0.300  31   2000   A   0.990
2  2011  0.290  30   4000   B   0.995
3  2012  0.275  14    600   NA    NA
4  2013  0.280  24    800   C   0.970
5  2014  0.295  18   1000   B   0.980
6  2015  0.330  26   7000   D   0.990
7  2016  0.315  40   9000   NA    NA
```

Also, I want to repeat this for all the 244 dataframes in each list, `h` and `g`.
I'd like to make a new list named `final` which contains the 244 combined dataframes.

How can I do this...?
All answers will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think you should instead use `merge`:

```
merge(df1, df2, by="year", all = T)
```

For your data:

```
df1 = data.frame(matrix(0, 7, 4))
names(df1) = c("year", "avg", "hr", "sal")
df1$year = 2010:2016
df1$avg = c(.3, .29, .275, .280, .295, .33, .315)
df1$hr = c(31, 30, 14, 24, 18, 26, 40)
df1$sal = c(2000, 4000, 600, 800, 1000, 7000, 9000)
df2 = data.frame(matrix(0, 5, 3))
names(df2) = c("year", "pos", "fld")
df2$year = c(2010, 2011, 2013, 2014, 2015)
df2$pos = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'D')
df2$fld = c(.99,.995,.97,.98,.99)
```

`cbind` is meant to `column-bind` two `dataframes` that are in all sense compatible. But what you aim to do is actual `merge`, where you want the elements from the two data frames not be discarded, and for missing values you get `NA` instead.

Comment: This solution only takes 2 df, is there a way to take more? Also it is not compatible with suubsettiing within the fuunction. I.E.
Table <- merge(select(Input1, FULL_NAME, NGENES,BETA,P), select(Input2, NGENES,BETA,P), select(Input3, FULL_NAME, NGENES,BETA,P), by = FULL_NAME, all = T)

Answer (score 5):

We can use `Map` with `cbind.fill` (from `rowr`) to `cbind` the corresponding 'data.frame' from 'h' and 'g'.

```
library(rowr)
Map(cbind.fill, h, g, MoreArgs = list(fill=NA))
```

#### Update

Based on the expected output showed, it seems like the OP wanted a `merge` instead of `cbind`

```
f1 <- function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE, by = 'year')
Map(f1, h, g)
#[[1]]
#  year   avg hr  sal  pos   fld
#1 2010 0.300 31 2000    A 0.990
#2 2011 0.290 30 4000    B 0.995
#3 2012 0.275 14  600 <NA>    NA
#4 2013 0.280 24  800    C 0.970
#5 2014 0.295 18 1000    B 0.980
#6 2015 0.330 26 7000    D 0.990
#7 2016 0.315 40 9000 <NA>    NA
```

Or as @Colonel Beauvel mentioned, this can be made compact

```
Map(merge, h, g, by='year', all=TRUE)
```

#### data

```
h <- list(structure(list(year = 2010:2016, avg = c(0.3, 0.29, 0.275, 
0.28, 0.295, 0.33, 0.315), hr = c(31L, 30L, 14L, 24L, 18L, 26L, 
 40L), sal = c(2000L, 4000L, 600L, 800L, 1000L, 7000L, 9000L)), .Names = c("year", 
 "avg", "hr", "sal"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
 "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")))

g <- list(structure(list(year = c(2010L, 2011L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L
), pos = c("A", "B", "C", "B", "D"), fld = c(0.99, 0.995, 0.97, 
0.98, 0.99)), .Names = c("year", "pos", "fld"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5")))
```

Comment: For the update, go for `Map(merge, h, g, by='year', all=T)`

Comment: rowr is deprecated from CRAN

Comment: @ACE Based on the updated answer, it is a different one

Comment: @akrun Thanks! I was just notifying where-ever rowr is used so others can know

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you could do this with `tidyverse` tools:

```
library(tidyverse)

h <- list()
g <- list()

h[[1]] <- tribble(
  ~year,  ~avg, ~hr,  ~sal,
  2010,  0.300,  31,  2000,
  2011,  0.290,  30,  4000,
  2012,  0.275,  14,   600,
  2013,  0.280,  24,   800,
  2014,  0.295,  18,  1000,
  2015,  0.330,  26,  7000,
  2016,  0.315,  40,  9000
)

g[[1]] <- tribble(
  ~year,  ~pos,  ~fld,
   2010,   "A",   0.990,
   2011,   "B",   0.995,
   2013,   "C",   0.970,
   2014,   "B",   0.980,
   2015,   "D",   0.990
)

map2(h, g, left_join)
```

Which produces:

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 7 x 6
   year   avg    hr   sal pos      fld
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
1  2010 0.3      31  2000 A      0.99 
2  2011 0.290    30  4000 B      0.995
3  2012 0.275    14   600 NA    NA    
4  2013 0.28     24   800 C      0.97 
5  2014 0.295    18  1000 B      0.98 
6  2015 0.33     26  7000 D      0.99 
7  2016 0.315    40  9000 NA    NA
```